# What is the difference between Multiple Inheritance and Polymorphism?

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

What is the difference between Multiple Inheritance and Polymorphism?

In a Book I red a line saying

**there is no support for multiple inheritances at class level. This means you can't extend more than one class at a time.**

Which is contradicting the concept of Polymorphism, described in the same book as

**polymorphism is the process of creating several objects from specific base classes**

Now if Multiple Inheritance is not allowed in PHP then how the Polymorphism is allowed?

Comment: PHP doesn't allow polymorphism...?

Comment: ...because it is a weakly type language

Comment: Then why does the text books explains the concept of Polymorphism in book of OOP in PHP

Comment: @SeanJa although It's not strictly polymorphism, the technique can still be applied. But it's called ducktypong in weakly type languages.

Comment: Guys please be specific and elaborative....

Comment: If you wanted to ask a PHP-specific question, please do so in the topic messages. Otherwise please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: @Parth Why does an OOP book on PHP explain Multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like Ikke said, **Multiple Inheritance** has nothing to do with Polymorphism.

If I could draw a class diagram, Multiple Inheritance looks like this:

```
Base A    Base B
  ^         ^
   \       /
    \     /
     Child
```

So, the class `Child` would inherit both attributes and behaviours from both classes. Many languages like Java and PHP don't allow this, but Python does.

**Polymorphism**, on the other hand, is when you can abstract out a specialisation. First of all, class diagram:

```
     Animal
     ^    ^
    /      \
   /        \
 Cat        Dog
```

And you may do the following:

```
// Assuming we have a pack of animals
// This is Java
for (Animal pet : pack)
    pet.speak();
```

Each `pet` will say different things depending on the implementation.

Comment: Ahaaa Great Explanation It was misconception in my Mind Thanks a lot Xavier......

Comment: The problem with polymorphism in php is that since return types are not enforced (it being a weakly typed language), there is no guarantee that `speak` actually returns a string. It might return a database object. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749712/is-what-seems-like-polymorphism-in-php-really-polymorphism )

Answer (score 3):

Multiple inheritance means an object inherits from two different parent classes. A ProgrammerBicyclist is both a Programmer and a Bicyclist. The problem arises when the Programmer class defines its member data `favorite_activity` as `hacking` while a Bicyclist also has `favorite_activity`, but it's `riding`. If you ask a ProgrammerBicyclist what her `favorite_activity` is, what's the correct answer?

Polymorphism deals with the behavior of objects. It lets you tell an object to do something and have the resulting action depend on the object's class, even if you don't know exactly what that is. So you come across a Person, though you don't know if it's a Programmer or a Cook, and you tell her to `perform_your_job()`. If it's a Programmer she will write code, if it's a Cook she will make a meal, but you don't have to specifically tell her to `write_code()` or `make_a_meal()`.

Comment: Can U pls be a bit elaborative for Polymorphism?.. Its interesting.. plsss do it...

Answer (score 1):

Those two have very little to do with each other.

Multiple inheritance is something that is static after compile time / runtime. Polymorphism is a technique where only on runtime actually is decided which method on a subtype is called.

PHP doesn't allow for multiple inheritance.