# Dynamic Polymorphism in PHP

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism

Is Dynamic Polymorphism in PHP is supported like template classes  or is the only way in using Polymorphism in PHP is abstract functions and overloading/overriding ?

Comment: I looked that up here: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Building-Dynamic-Web-Pages-with-Polymorphism-in-PHP-5/2/ and it seems like a TOTAL waste of processing... perhaps there's something I don't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should enlighten you: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like Template Classes, but you can very much achieve different runtime behavior through the use Abstract Classes and Interfaces as well as the utilization of Design Patterns like State, Decorator, Strategy and others.

related: [Is what seems like polymorphism in PHP really polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749712/is-what-seems-like-polymorphism-in-php-really-polymorphism)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interfaces as well as abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces to add common functionality to classes. You can of course also override specific functions and extend classes as well. The most common way that I polymorph the functionality of my classes is starting with a base (template) class and extending it for each fork in its usage tree.