# Polymorphism is nothing but overwriting functions of inherited classes?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstraction

Here is a code I am taking from another post:
[Is what seems like polymorphism in PHP really polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749712/is-what-seems-like-polymorphism-in-php-really-polymorphism)

```
class Animal {
    var $name;
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    function speak() {
        return "Woof, woof!";
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    function speak() {
        return "Meow...";
    }
}

$animals = array(new Dog('Skip'), new Cat('Snowball'));


foreach($animals as $animal) {
    print $animal->name . " says: " . $animal->speak() . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: The question is, is this statement true?
What I can see happening here, is we assign two functions  with the same name to different classes,

Is there a one or two sentence explanation for polymorphism

Comment: You can use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for polymorphism in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

> Polymorphism means that the sender of a stimulus does not need to know
>   the receiving instance’s class. The receiving instance can belogin to
>   an arbitrary class.
>
> ([Object-Oriented Software Engineering: A  Use Case Driven Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201544350),
>   p.55)

In this case, the sender is the print statement that calls `$animal->name` and `$animal->speak()`. The object instance can be of arbitrary class that implements the attribute `name` and the method `speak` while the whole thing still works. Thus, by this definition, polymorphism.

Or else, what do you mean by polymorphism? (Different people could have different understanding to the same word)

Comment: Just quoting a book. Not mine. What is the definition that you know of?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, polymorphism is the ability of a given class of providing a set of functions/methods and let its specializations redefine their implementations.

Comment: I think you're specifically talking about argument-based polymorphism. Not polymorphism in general.